# Tkinter Entry attribute user result

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to obtain the user's input, store it as a variable and print that variable (for testing), but when the entire program is ran, no results are printed.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os.path
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk

def on_change(entry):
    inp = entry.widget.get()
    print inp

root = tk.Tk()

#Makes a canvas for objects    
canvas = Canvas(root, height=100, width=400)
#Displays the canvas
canvas.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

label = Label(root, text="Enter an element or the atomic number from 1 to 118.").grid(row=0, column=2)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind("<Return>", on_change)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
entry.focus()

def entry_delete(evt):
    entry.delete(0, 'end')

entry.bind("<Return>", entry_delete)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please update your code so it doesn't throw a tkinter warning and doesn't try to import PIL for no reason?

Comment: You're binding two different functions (`on_change` and `entry_delete`) to the same event (`<Return>`). The 2nd function is replacing the first one.

Comment: Are you _trying_ to call both methods on the same event here (in which case it's a dup), or was this the kind of silly mistake none of us can ever find in our own code after hours of debugging but can easily spot in someone else's  (in which case it's a typo), or is there a different question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a binding on `<Return>`, then later you overwrite that binding with a different binding.

If you want to bind to multiple functions, you need to set the `add` parameter to `True`:

```
entry.bind("<Return>", entry_delete, add=True)
```

In my experience, it's best to always have a single binding. If you need the binding to do multiple things, create a function to call those multiple things:

```
def on_return(event):
    on_change(event)
    entry_delete(event)
entry.bind("<Return>", on_return)
```